# JQM, Back button not working in android

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

The back button using 'data-rel="back"' works fine while going back from one page to another
inside the  html file which contains multiple pages

but it doesnot work while moving back from one html page to another html page.

I have tried data-add-back-btn="true", but it did not work.

my code looks like:

```html
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Every thing works fine in web browser. its only creating problems when compiling for mobile or running on an emulator.

I guess it has something to do with cordova/phonegap and not JQM per se.

Comment: its hard to tell without seeing any code. However; if you are using changePage to go from page1 to page2; make sure you haven't set changeHash:false. That could prevent back from working.